# How can hosting providers give you a dedicated IP adresses?

Tags: ip, ipv4

Some hosting providers give you an option to get a dedicated IP address with your hosting package. For example: Digital Ocean gives every droplet that you create its own dedicated IPv4 address.

I can think of Digital Ocean having some kind of contract with an ISP but I was more interested in how smaller hosting providers can do this.

So how is it possible that hosting providers can give you a dedicated IP for your host / application that runs on their servers?

Comment: Anyone can buy or request public IP addresses for their company or organization. When you buy public IP addresses on, for instance, auctions you own them and can use them for whatever you like.

Comment: Digital Ocean *is* an ISP operating their own network.

Comment: @TeunVink Well that explains a lot. Cown How would a smaller hosting provider do this? Lets say someone at home has a server and they want to start hosting some servers and their clients want dedicated IP's.

Comment: @RamonRobben it depends, if the company sees the opportunity to make money i don't see why not. IP addresses are not that expensive to acquire and IPv6 is practically free.

Comment: @Cown, I think your original comment, with expanded explanation, would bew a good answer.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin I have not yet found a suitable answer for my question.

Answer (score 3):

Converting comment to an answer.

Anyone can buy or request public IP addresses for their company or organization. When you buy public IP addresses on, for instance, auctions you own them and can use them for whatever you like.

If a small company sees the opportunity to make money they can easily buy a small amount of public IP addresses and start offering customers dedicated IP addresses. IP addresses are not that expensive to acquire and IPv6 is practically free.